# In my ts vue3 code, how can I enable changing of pictures using the file picker I have implemented?

Tags: typescript, vuejs3

i write code to open file picker and it opens it but now when i try to change picture it wont work whatever i tried so can someone help me to do this because i try to change pic and it wont work

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
const button = document.getElementById('myButton');

```
if (button) {
    button.addEventListener('click', () => {
        const input = document.createElement('input');
        input.type = 'file';

        input.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
            const file = event.target.files[0];
            const reader = new FileReader();

            reader.addEventListener('load', () => {
                const imageData = reader.result;
                
                console.log('Selected file:', file);
                console.log('Image data:', imageData);
            });

            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        });

        input.click();
    });
}
```

});
filepicker opens but i dont know how to modify code to when want to change pic it changes(without API)

Comment: That's not Vue, but regular JS. Did you add that tag accidentally?